# How can I send more then one response to client from a Httpserver base on Netty

Tags: java, netty, httpserver

How can I send more then one response to client from a Httpserver base on Netty?

I am trying to make a httpserver by netty and it works.
Now I have a question,can I send more then one response to client from a Httpserver ?
For example, the client requests the server from a web browser, and server responses "hello" then responses "bye" several seconds later.

I add three handles:

```
    sc.pipeline().addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
    sc.pipeline().addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
    sc.pipeline().addLast(new HttpChannelHandler());
```

In the  HttpChannelHandler ,I tried to response twice,but failed

```
public class HttpChannelHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            //the content response to the client
            String resp_content = "hello";
            request = (HttpRequest) msg;
            boolean keepaLive = HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request);
            FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1,
                    OK, Unpooled.copiedBuffer(resp_content.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH,
                    response.content().readableBytes());
            if (keepaLive) {
                response.headers().set(CONNECTION, KEEP_ALIVE);
                //first response
                ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
                content = "test";
                response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH,
                        response.content().readableBytes());
                //second response,but failed
                // exception io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
                response.content().writeBytes(resp_content.getBytes());
                ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No thats not possible... HTTP is a "request/response" style protocol. Once you sent a response to the client you can only send another one when you receive another request.